# How to fix the alignment of Buttons in ChoiceDialog?

Tags: dialog-window

Consider the following example:

```
ChoiceDialog["Pick one", {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d"}]
```

It produces appropriately sized buttons in version 11.3.0 but in version 12.0.0 it produces large first two buttons and smaller other two. Is there an option to fix this in version 12.0.0. The documentation is sparse for this function.

Comment: I just tried it on a Mac running 12.0.0 and it looks fine.  Are you running this on Windows?  If so, it seems that it might be a platform issue of some sort.  Looks fine means that the buttons are all the same size and the text is centered within the button.  I don't know how to add a picture to this comment - it shows what I see.

Comment: @MarkR yes I am using Windows but this issue didn't exist on Windows when running 11.3.0 so must have been introduced at 12 for Windows.